# Concat two lists in terraform

Tags: list, terraform, concatenation

I have the following strings and lists, i need to merge both the lists.

```
str1 = "Cost"
str2 = "peervalue"
str3 = "date"
str4 = "value2"
samplelist1 = ["network_spoke1","network_spoke2","network_spoke3","network_spoke4"]
samplelist2 = ["valueA","valueB","valueC","valueD"]
```

I need the output in the below format. How can that be achieved

```
FinalList = [
"Cost,network_spoke1,peervalue,date,valueA,value2"
"Cost,network_spoke2,peervalue,date,valueB,value2"
"Cost,network_spoke3,peervalue,date,valueC,value2"
"Cost,network_spoke4,peervalue,date,valueD,value2"
]
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
  FinalList = [for v1, v2 in zipmap(local.samplelist1, local.samplelist2): "${local.str1},${v1},${local.str2},${local.str3},${v2},${local.str4}"]
```

Comment: Zipmap does not allow duplicate entries. It displays the item with highest index. How to display all the items and concat the strings and lists.

Comment: I mean the samplelist1 is like samplelist1 = ["network_spoke1", "network_spoke1","network_spoke3", "network_spoke4"].                                                                 FinalList displays only 3 values instead of 4. I need all the 4 items to get displayed.

Comment: Any help on the above comments

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine:

```
str1 = "Cost"
str2 = "peervalue"
str3 = "date"
str4 = "value2"

samplelist1 = ["network_spoke1", "network_spoke2""network_spoke3", "network_spoke4"]
                   
samplelist2 = ["valueA", "valueB", "valueC", "valueD"]
finalist = [
    str1, (samplelist1[0]), str2, str3, samplelist2[0], str4,
    str1, (samplelist1[1]), str2, str3, samplelist2[1], str4,
    str1, (samplelist1[2]), str2, str3, samplelist2[2], str4,
    str1, (samplelist1[3]), str2, str3, samplelist2[3], str4
]

for i in finalist:
    print(i)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).